# Update very deep object with spread operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, spread-syntax

I've got an object that looks like this:

```
  state: {
    "1": {
      "show": false,
      "description": "one",
      "children": {
        "1": { "show": false, "description": "one" },
        "2": { "show": false, "description": "one" }
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "show": false,
      "description": "one",
      "children": {
        "1": { "show": false, "description": "one" },
        "2": { "show": false, "description": "one" }
      }
    }
  }
```

I've got a for loop that change the children "show" property to the opposite boolean. So I try to update the value with this but doesn't worked.

```
      for (var childKey in state[appClassId].children) {
        newState = {
          ...state,
          [appClassId]: {
            children: {
              [childKey]: { ...state[appClassId].children[childKey], show: !state[appClassId].children[childKey].show}

            }
          }
```

"appClassId" variable is a variable that I get from the action.

How can I update every key in the child property for instance state.1.children.1.show

Comment: Could you look at [Normalizing State Shape](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html) from the redux documentation? I think it will help you to normalize your state and be able to update it easily!

Comment: It's normalized take a look at the example it gives in your link.

Comment: Actually, as author of that "Structuring Reducers" section, I think the "Immutable Update Patterns" section is more relevant: http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html

Answer (score 4):

With the help of @markerikson author of:

http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html

I was able to update that deep level of nested data:

The object to update are the all objects under "children" property of this object:

```
 state: {
    "1": {
      "show": false,
      "description": "one",
      "children": {
        "1": { "show": false, "description": "one" },
        "2": { "show": false, "description": "one" }
      }
    },
    "2": {
      "show": false,
      "description": "one",
      "children": {
        "1": { "show": false, "description": "one" },
        "2": { "show": false, "description": "one" }
      }
    }
  }
```

And the code to update it is:

```
let newState = {};
newState = { ...state, newState }

for (var childKey in newState[appClassId].children) {
  newState = {
    ...newState,
    [appClassId]: {
      ...newState[appClassId],
      children: {
        ...newState[appClassId].children,
        [childKey]: {
          ...newState[appClassId].children[childKey],
          show: !newState[appClassId].children[childKey].show
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend leaning on [a utility library like `lodash.js`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4) in addition to the spread operator if you're doing anything more complex than assigning a value or two.

Assuming that the number of `appClassId`s inside `state` and `children` inside each `appClass` are completely dynamic:

```js
import { reduce } from 'lodash'

const newState = reduce(state, (modifiedState, appClass, appClassId) => {
  const { children } = appClass
  // toggle show for each child (non-mutating)
  const toggledChildren = reduce(children, (newChildren, child, childId) => {
    return {
      ...newChildren,
      [childId]: { ...child, show: !child.show }
    }
  }, {})

  // persist modified children within the appClass
  return {
    ...modifiedState,
    [appClassId]: {
      ...appClass,
      children: toggledChildren
    }
  }
}, {})
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
const originalChildren = state[appClassId].children;
let updatedChildren = {};

for (var child in originalChildren) {
   if (originalChildren.hasOwnProperty(child)) {
      updatedChildren = {
        ...updatedChildren,
        [child]: { ...originalChildren[child], show: !originalChildren[child].show }
      };
   }
}

const newState = {
  ...state,
  [appClassId]: {
    ...state[appClassId],
    children: { ...originalChildren, ...updatedChildren }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another example,

```
let test = [
  { id: 1, name: 'Phone',
    Devices: [
      { id: 1, name: 'BlackBerry',GroupId: 1 },
      { id: 2, name: 'Iphone', GroupId: 1 }
    ]
  }, { id: 2, name: 'Speaker',
    Devices: [
      { id: 3, name: 'Senheiser', GroupId: 2 },
      { id: 4, name: 'Simbadda', GroupId: 2 }
    ]
  }
];

const GroupId = 1;
const device = {
  id: 5,
  name: 'Android',
  GroupId: GroupId
}


let Group = [...test];

const idx = test.findIndex(payload => {
  return payload.id === GroupId
});

console.log(Group[idx].Devices = [...Group[idx].Devices, device]);
```

Hope it will help